# Lambda accessing Elasticsearch times out after about a day

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-elasticsearch

I am working on a project which uses an SQS triggered Lambda to ingest some content into AWS Elasticsearch.

The Lambda and the Elasticsearch service are located in the same VPC.

The source code is very simple and its size is 10.5kB (mostly static resources ie. xsl files).

The libraries used are packaged in a separate layer.

When I first deploy the Lambda, everything works correctly, the lambda gets invoked thousands of times and for about a day or two, everything works as expected. However, it then starts timing out and once it does, it always does until I do a fresh redeploy.

This occurs whether I use the `elasticsearch-py` client or `requests.get`.

Increasing the timeout or memory allocation does not help.

Recycling objects or re-instantiating everything on each invocation does not make any difference, either.

Has anyone experienced similar issues?

Comment: You need some insight into whats happening. Get some log aggregation scheme going so you can observe response times/codes etc and get a better insight into what is happening.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues - got lots of Cloudwatch logging in place already. Response times are well within the timeout set and are always 200s when the service is working. When it does not work, they just timeout ie. there is no response...

Comment: Where and how are you making your connection to Elasticsearch (for example, creating the Elasticsearch client)? Are you using authentication? If so, what type and how are you providing it?

Comment: hello @kielni - there is no authentication at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

‍♂️ This turned out to be a problem with our deployment setup...

My project interacts with an Elasticsearch instance which is created by another team Terraform deployment.

When I create the resources for my project environment (also in Terraform), I add an `aws_security_group_rule` to the existing security group:

```
data "aws_security_group" "es_sg" {
  name = var.security_group_name
}
```

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "allow_lambda_access_to_es" {
  type = "ingress"
  to_port = 443
  protocol = "tcp"
  from_port = 443
  security_group_id = data.aws_security_group.es_sg.id
  source_security_group_id = module.lambda.sg_id
  description = "Ingestion lambda access to ES"
}
```

When the other team re-apply, the rule is deleted...

The fix for this was to get the other team to define their rule as a separate resource instead of inline.